# Antonym of facetious

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

[***facetious*** (Oxford Dictionaries):](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/facetious)

> *treating serious issues with deliberately inappropriate humour; flippant*

I'm looking for a word that means the total opposite; to treat humorus or non-serious issues with deliberately inappropriate gravity. There exist a few words and phrases that can get the idea across (cantankerous, old grouch, stick-in-the-mud), but they usually speak to more than just my specific sought definition. Also just a word would be preferable; phrases generally aren't nearly as satisfying in their delivery. Thanks.

Comment: Pompous fits with your examples but they aren't really deliberate, they are more like manifestations of personality. Deadpan sounds closer to me: something you deliberately do.

Comment: Are you after a noun or an adjective? It would make a big difference: if an adjective, it could be applied to a noun that adds the notion of an attempt (or a successful attempt) at humor.

Comment: Might be something on this list to help you: http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/facetious

Comment: Jacinto, the antonym of facetious is serious. I can feel the Portuguese, believe it. You have said: old grouch, cantankerous, stick-in-the-mud which are not antonyms of facetious. Be facetious is fancy talk for be funny or comical. "I was being facetious" v "I was being serious".  "I was being light hearted" v. "I am dead serious".

Comment: @Lambie I didn't say anything; I've only superficially edited the question. You should address your comment to Axalon57.

Comment: If someone accused me of being facetious, on one of those rare occasions when I was not, I'd likely reply, "No, I'm being dead serious."

Comment: Whoops, right, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tongue-in-cheek](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tongue-in-cheek): "If you say something tongue in ​cheek, you ​intend it to be ​understood as a ​joke, ​although you might ​appear to be ​serious"

Edit: @Hugh Meyers' reponse of [deadpan](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/deadpan) should probably be mentioned in an answer rather than just as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The word [straight](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/straight) may be useful, but in your case requires additional words around it for context, such as:

- [playing it straight](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/straight)
- staying straight-faced (or perhaps, [poker-faced](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/poker+face))
- being the [straight man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_man_(stock_character))

Comment: Also "with a straight face".

Answer (score 0):

**Earnest**

Being earnest is essentially being serious, and being sincere.

[http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/earnest]

[http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/earnest]

Answer (score -2):

See whether that's appropriate : **scolastic** **1.** of, relating to, or befitting schools, scholars, or education
**2.** pedantic or precise
**3.** (Historical Terms) (often capital) characteristic of or relating to the medieval Schoolmen
n
**4.** a student or pupil
**5.** a person who is given to quibbling or logical subtleties; pedant
**6.** (Historical Terms) (often capital) a disciple or adherent of scholasticism; Schoolman
**7.** (Roman Catholic Church)
a. a Jesuit student who is undergoing a period of probation prior to commencing his theological studies
b. the status and position of such a student
**8.** (Art Terms) a formalist in art